# Does Spark internally use Map-Reduce?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Is Spark using Map Reduce internally ? (its own map reduce)

The first time I heard somebody tell me, "Spark uses map-reduce", I was so confused, I always learned that spark was an alterative for Hadoop Map-Reduce.

After I checked in Google I found a web-site that make some too short explanation about that : https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spark-use-mapreduce

But the rest of Internet only compares Spark and Map-Reduce.

Then somebody explained to me that when spark make an RDD the data is split in different datasets and if you are using for example SPAR.SQL a query that should not be a map reduce like:

```
select student 
from Table_students 
where name = "Enrique"
```

Internally Spark is doing a map reduce to retrieve the Data( from the different datasets).

Is this true ?

If I'm using Spark Mlib, to use machine learning, I always heard that machine learning is not compatible with map reduce because it needed many interactions and map-reduce use batch processing..

In Spark Mlib, is Spark Internally using Map reduce too ?

Comment: I think you are confused between Hadoop's MapReduce and MapRecude Algorithm.
Spark Mlib still use map reduce . So the question may change to 
[Why spark is faster or better for machine learning] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572529/why-is-spark-faster-than-hadoop-map-reduce?rq=1)

Comment: Hi @howie , well ...  "Why spark is better for machine learnirng" is not my question, the question that I really have is: "its true, that spark use map reduce internally"  like you say "Spark Mlib still use map reduce", well,  how ? Where can I find more Info about that. Thanks for answer

Comment: Let me clarify your question, Do you know the different between Spark's MapReduce and Hadoop's MapReduce? If not,  this video have good answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaw5kG9q6xw . Or your question is how  Spark Mlib use map reduce for machine learning program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Apache Spark different from the Hadoop approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033624/how-is-apache-spark-different-from-the-hadoop-approach). Additionally [MapReduce or Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22167684/10465355)

Comment: @user10465355  In your links are comparing spark with map reduce, my question is  if Spark is using map reduce too.

Comment: Sorry ~ I would like to make a correction of my answer. Actually spark use DAG(Directed Acyclic Graph) not tradicational mapreduce. You can think of it as an alternative to Map Reduce. While MR has just two steps (map and reduce), DAG can have multiple levels that can form a tree structure. So you can write mapreduce like program in spark, but internal spark run on DAG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spark features an advanced Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) engine supporting cyclic data flow. Each Spark job creates a DAG of task stages to be performed on the cluster. Compared to MapReduce, which creates a DAG with two predefined stages - Map and Reduce, DAGs created by Spark can contain any number of stages. DAG is a strict generalization of MapReduce model. 
This allows some jobs to complete faster than they would in MapReduce, with simple jobs completing after just one stage, and more complex tasks completing in a single run of many stages, rather than having to be split into multiple jobs.

So, Spark can write map-reduce program, but actually use DAG inside.

Reference:

- [Directed Acyclic Graph DAG in Apache Spark](https://data-flair.training/blogs/dag-in-apache-spark/)
- [What is Directed Acyclic Graph in Apache Spark?](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/131010/what-is-directed-acyclic-graph-in-apache-spark.html)
- [What are the Apache Spark concepts around its DAGexecution engine, and its overall architecture?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-Apache-Spark-concepts-around-its-DAG-Directed-Acyclic-Graph-execution-engine-and-its-overall-architecture)
- [How-to: Translate from MapReduce to Apache Spark](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/09/how-to-translate-from-mapreduce-to-apache-spark/)